# Fragment Transaction not working when using AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-appcompat, back-stack

I have a typical application. An activity which has a FrameLayout and in this layout I want to switch between fragments. This is typically and easily done with:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.ac_container, new FrOverview())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

The problem is, that even if I use `.addToBackStack(null)` (And I know it's been added 'cause the stack count increases) when I press back I exit the application. I have been trying a lot of different code stuff and checked most threads here on Stackoverflow but I can't get it to work with code (method calls etc.).

But! I can get it to work, by changing the extended class of my activity class. If my class extends `Activity`, it works fine. But if I use `AppCompatActivity` (which in turn extends `FragmentActivity`) then it has the bad behaviour as explained earlier.

Feels like this has to be an error on Androids part, I am not doing anything wrong to my knowledge.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this? i.e. get the back functionality and keep the ActionBar!

Comment: use `getSupportedFragmentManager` to make fragment transaction and change your fragments extends to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: FrOverview() is of android.support.v4.app.Fragment type or android.app.Fragment type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` uses the `SupportFragmentManager`, you need
to switch to SupportFragment and SupportFragmentManager

Comment: Which then in turn needs me to change the `Fragments` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` from the support Library ;)
Thanks!